# Windows 8.1 recovery make boot

Tags: windows-8.1

I have notebook Samsung Ativ Book 8 and my OS(license) is not launching,.

F4 and other ways in "diagnostic menu" I have tried do not work. I have no "recovery disk", license key and restore points. Service center changed HDD to SSD and reinstalled the OS one year ago.

I booted from a LiveCD(Ubuntu) and with GParted I found partiton REC2 - 22GB and REC1(FAT32) - 1GB. If I understand correctly I need to force make boot these partitons.

I only need factory options recovery.
Help me, please, how can i do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Make LiveUSB\CD with software launching the install.wim
2. Enter with help LiveUSB\CD
3. Find and make active "hidding partition with recovery data"
4. With help software find and launch install.wim
5. Begin install Windows from "recovery partition"